# How to filter and access child element from nested array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following array of objects and I would like to get the innermost child attribute if it matches the outer condition:

My condition should be if `objArray.displayValue` matches "display2" and its `types.displayValue` matches "inner_display4" then return its value, which is 4.

```
objArray = [
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "displayValue": "display1",
    "types": [
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "displayValue": "inner_display1",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "name2",
        "displayValue": "inner_display2",
        "value": "2"
      },
      {
        "name": "name3",
        "displayValue": "inner_display3",
        "value": "3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "cdf",
    "displayValue": "display2",
    "types": [
      {
        "name": "name4",
        "displayValue": "inner_display4",
        "value": "4"
      },
      {
        "name": "name5",
        "displayValue": "inner_display5",
        "value": "5"
      },
      {
        "name": "name6",
        "displayValue": "inner_display6",
        "value": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Did you try? What happened? What is the problem in doing this? Do you know how to iterate over an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```js
const find = (data, displayValue, innerDisplayValue) => 
  data.reduce((res, item) => {
    if(res || item.displayValue !== displayValue) return res
    const type =  item.types.find(t => t.displayValue === innerDisplayValue)
    return type? type.value: res
  }, undefined)


const objArray = [{
  "name": "abc",
  "displayValue": "display1",
  "types": [{
    "name": "name1",
    "displayValue": "inner_display1",
    "value": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "name2",
    "displayValue": "inner_display2",
    "value": "2"
  }, {
    "name": "name3",
    "displayValue": "inner_display3",
    "value": "3"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "cdf",
  "displayValue": "display2",
  "types": [{
    "name": "name4",
    "displayValue": "inner_display4",
    "value": "4"
  }, {
    "name": "name5",
    "displayValue": "inner_display5",
    "value": "5"
  }, {
    "name": "name6",
    "displayValue": "inner_display6",
    "value": "6"
  }]
}]

console.log(find(objArray, 'display2', 'inner_display4'))
console.log(find(objArray, 'display2', 'inner_display40'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

First find the object that has the correct displayValue and then filter the types to return the object you're looking for. Once you have the correct types object destructure the value.

The const `displayValue` is your result

Hope the code is a little bit clear :)

```
const findByDisplayValue = (dv) => objArray.find((obj) => obj.displayValue === dv);
const { types } = findByDisplayValue('display2');

const getType = (typeValue) => types.filter((type) => type.displayValue === typeValue);
const [{ displayValue }] = getType('inner_display4');
```